# can not do apt update, i get the forbidden 403 error

Tags: apt, package-managers

I have a kubuntu 16.04 on my computer and when i want to do a apt update it get a 403 forbidden error. I visited a lot of  web page on the internet and they didn't helped me. how can i fix this issue.

every time i do apt-get update i get these results:

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1) xenial InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1) xenial Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release
  503  Service Unavailable
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release
  503  DNS error for hostname archive.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution. If archive.ubuntu.com refers to a configured cache repository, please check the corresponding configuration file.
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release
  503  DNS error for hostname archive.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution. If archive.ubuntu.com refers to a configured cache repository, please check the corresponding configuration file.
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please add more details to your post.

Comment: i added the details

Comment: apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs -- your error is there on the first line. What are you exactly trying to do with the update function?

Comment: you get 503 not 403, you should change your dns server settings and add a working dns server.